# access laravel 5.2 many to many pivot . but it returns null

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to access the middle table attributes of many to many relationships using pivot but it return nulls.

```
class User extends Modal
{


   public function packages()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Package');
    }
}


Class Package extend Model

    {

      public function users()
       {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
       }


    }
```

`$package->pivot->created_at`

but it returns null.

although i have a package associated to user.

Comment: Not enough information for a meaningful answer

Answer (score 2):

By default, only the model keys will be present on the pivot object. If your pivot table contains extra attributes, you must specify them when defining the relationship:

```
public function packages()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Package')->withPivot('created_at');
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withPivot('created_at');
}
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
class User extends Modal
{


   public function packages()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Package')->withTimestamps();
    }
}


Class Package extend Model

    {

      public function users()
       {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withTimestamps();
       }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have timestamps in your table.

```
    Schema::table('user_package', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

you can do this by adding  in your migrations

```
  class User extends Modal
{


  public function packages()
   {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Package')->withTimestamps();
   }
 }


 Class Package extend Model
     {

  public function users()
   {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withTimestamps();
   }


}
```

if you dont add this line your timestamps will not be saved in database.

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withTimestamps();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: my table doesn't have the timestamps.